# Can every partially ordered set (POSET) take the form of a directed acyclic graph (DAG)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory

A **POSET** (Partially ordered set) is a set on the elements of which we have established a **partial order relation ($\leq$)**, i.e. a relation which is:

1. **reflexive**: $x\leq x,$ for every x in S
2. **anti-symmetric**: $x \leq y \wedge y \leq x \Rightarrow x=y $
3. **transitive**: $x\leq y, y\leq x \Rightarrow x\leq z$

My question is if every POSET can take the form of a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) if we view its elements as the nodes and the relation itself as the edge set.

Comment: It's better than a DAG, it's a transitive DAG. If you represent the edges of the poset's [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) as arcs in the upward direction, and take the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of the resulting (acyclic) digraph, you get the DAG of the poset.

Comment: @M.Vinay : the opposite operation is also interesting ? removing the maximum of edges without changing the binary relation by specifying it stays transitive. then the graph becomes ..

Comment: @user1952009 Then you'll get the Hasse diagram back. Edges now represent (the more restricted) "covering" relation rather the the whole relation.

Comment: ok thanks, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction

Comment: Thank you very much all!! That's exactly what I wanted to verify plus a few more things I will try to learn about.

Comment: @user1952009 You might like to know that a [preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) (a reflexive and transitive relation) can also be a represented by a transitive digraph (not acyclic) in the same way. But now, you can define an equivalence relation on the vertex set by making any two vertices equivalent if each is related to the other. Then the equivalence classes form [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component), so that any cycle is contained entirely in exactly one strongly connected component or equivalence class.

Comment: Now construct a new digraph with each equivalence class of the earlier graph taken as a *single vertex*, such that there is an arc from one vertex to another if there is at least one arc between the corresponding equivalence classes in the original graph. Now the new graph is a transitive DAG and represents a partially ordered set.

Comment: You can do the same with no reference to graphs at all. You just define the same equivalence relation on the preordered set, and construct a new set with elements as the equivalence classes. Define a relation on this, with classes $[x]$ and $[y]$ being related as $[x] \le [y]$ if some $x' \in [x]$ (in the original preordered set) is related to some $y' \in [y]$. Then $\le$ is a partial order on the set of equivalence classes.

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems very interesting too.

Answer (score 9):

YES. Every POSET can take the form of a DAG.

However, in order to obtain a less cluttered graph, you’d better avoid drawing every single edge. (see figure) 
You can omit the edges that can be inferred from the reflexive and transitive properties. 
Moreover you can arrange nodes in order to orient every edge upward and omit vector tips.
In this way you obtain a Hasse diagram: it is just a stripped down DAG.
[image: DAG compared to Hesse diagram]